# Animate scroll to a div with an ID

Tags: javascript, html, animation, scroll

I know this has probably been asked before but I couldn't find the right answer.

I'm trying to have a link, when you click it, scrolls the page to an element with an ID, with just javascript, and I get to control the speed.

I know about:

```
document.getElementById('youridhere').scrollIntoView();
```

and that didn't work. It just snapped into view. I also tried `scrollBy` but that didn't work since it works in increments. I can write it up to check the remaining distance to the element and if it's less than the increment, then only move what's left, but that seems way too bulky.

I tried `scrollTo` as well but that wasn't helping much either.

Is there a cleaner way of doing this?

This needs to be javascript only. Here is a jquery equivalent:

```
var top = target.offset().top;

$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: top}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way to smooth scroll. I would use `setInterval` and `scrollBy` an increment on each iteration, then `clearInterval` when done.

You could also check the jQuery source to see how they do it.